# Which dependencies to add to scala project for Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, import

I need to use the following libraries -

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

what are the dependences to be added to scala on intellij

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? You can't add spark dependencies now for Scala 2.12 -- only for 2.10 or 2.11

Answer (score 3):

For those you used in `import`, you generally need

If you are using `maven`

```
<properties>
    <spark.version>2.2.0</spark.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If you you are using `sbt`

```
val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % sparkVersion
}
```

Where `spark.version` and `sparkVersion` are the versions of spark used. `2.2.0` is used here but you can make a choice of any other.

If you don't use `sbt` or `maven` you need to download these libraries jar file and add in you project.

Hope this helps

Comment: I hope the answer helped you, If this helped can you accept as answer?

Answer (score 0):

As Shankar rightly answered, you can either use Maven or Sbt built tool. The best way I like to start my scala project especially with Intelij is to run the `sbt new` on command line as such:

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
```

After this, you simply import the project into Intelij and then Intelij auto detects that it's an `sbt` project.

Then I can add any dependencies easily in the `build.sbt` file as described by Shankar.

Note that after adding each dependency, Intelij detects the changes and ask you to refresh the project.

So in your case a simple `build.sbt` file will look like this:

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
     inThisBuild(List(
     organization := "com.example",
     scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
     version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)),
name := "scalatweet",
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  scalaTest % Test,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % sparkVersion
 )
 )
```

And to ensure that you add the right dependency for your project, search for the library in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) and take note of the Scala version you are using for dependency compatibility.